# OMNeT++ 5.5.1 & SimuLTE on Windows - Debugging Error

Tags: eclipse, debugging, omnet++, simulte

I am using OMNeT++ 5.5.1 with INET-3.6.6 and SimuLTE-1.1.0.
When I debug examples in INET (for example AODV routing), the debugging works fine.
However, when I am trying to debug an example provided by simuLTE, I am getting an error:

> **Inconsistent Configuration Naming for 'lte'**

```
Cannot find or identify debug configuration for project 'lte' To be able to automatically switch between configurations, they should be named in a way that one (and only one) of them contains the word 'release' while the other contains 'debug'.
```

I have checked and verified that liblte_dbg.dll exists at both placed, i.e., at "C:\omnetpp-5.5.1\samples\lte\src" and "C:\omnetpp-5.5.1\samples\lte\out\clang-debug\src"

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Any help that how I can fix this error in order to start debugging of simuLTE?

PS: I have set simuLTE as lte.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the SimuLTE project in the OMNeT IDE and under Build Configurations-

> Set Active select gcc-debug .